# Arch Linux - KDE Keyboard layout

Tags: arch-linux, x11, kde

I need my keyboard layout set to the portuguese layout, and it has been set for weeks, out of nowhere it stopped working.

I have it set to pt on KDE and localectl, on TTY it works, on KDE it uses what is essentially the US layout even when it says it-s using the PT layout.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug on xkeyboard-config version 2.26-1 (https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/61634)
While you wait for it to be fixed you can downgrade the package to the previous version (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/downgrading_packages)